# Is it possible to route to another angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, url, angularjs-ng-route

As I migrate my project to become full angluarjs, I still have a complex page which I cannot yet merge as a partial so that I end up with a sigle one-page app.

Therefore I have two (angularjs) apps, the main app (guideApp) should route to the second (accidentsSelector) thru the url scheme #/accidents/search3D

My current controller is as follows:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/corporate',             {controller:'pageCtrl', templateUrl:'corn.page.corporate.html'})

    // Accidents (Diagnostic en culture)
    .when('/accidents',             {redirectTo:'/accidents/search'})
    .when('/accidents/search',      {redirectTo:'/accidents/search2D'})
    .when('/accidents/search3D',    {redirectTo:'corn.coverflow.html'})
    .when('/accidents/search2D',    {controller:'pageCtrl', templateUrl:'corn.page.accident.search.html'})
```

I would I should update the /accidents/seach3D so that it loads and opens the second app?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this:

```
.when('/accidents/seach3D', {controller:'redirectCtrl', templateUrl:'redirect.html'})
```

and then in your redirectCtrl you can have:

```
$window.location.href = 'another app'
```